# Apache FileUtils listFiles

Tags: java, file, apache-commons-io

Hey everyone I'm trying to get a List of directories.  I'm using FileUtils listFiles().

I want to do something like this: listFiles(File,IOFileFilter,false).  My real questions is  how I can implement the accept() from the IOFileFilter so I can check if current File is a directory?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8):

File has an [`isDirectory()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory()) method you can call, so:

```
final IOFileFilter dirs = new IOFileFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        return file.isDirectory();
    }
}

final IOFileFilter none = new IOFileFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File file) {return false;}
};

listFiles(file, dirs, none);
```

Comment: Yes thank you that was exactly what I was looking for.  I know File has isDirectory().  It's just me that I like the other way better.

Answer (score 0):

I find Java 7+'s [java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/SimpleFileVisitor.html) described in [The Java™ Tutorials, Walking the File Tree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) extremely helpful.